# How can i send values to a Jenkins script?

Tags: powershell, jenkins

I have a Jenkins job and in that job the first thing that runs is a powershell script that I want to capture user inputs values and set them as global variables that are used through out the Jenkins job.
Now i want the user to be able to put these values in from their machine and then run the job with these values ?

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: In case anybody else finds this answer. Please see the comments below. This should not be used for credentials! As the communication can be secured by TLS, the credentials will still be visible in build logs etc.

You need to check the `This project is parameterized` checkbox in the settings of your job in Jenkins. Then define the name, type etc.

The given name is already accessible via standard syntax.
In shell script `${nameOfParam}` or `%nameOfParam` (depending on your shell / os).
In pipelines they are also accessible via `params.nameOfParam`.

You can set these variables via GUI using `Build with parameters` or via API call `http://<JENKINS_URL>/job/<JOB_NAME>/buildWithParameters/nameOfParam=foo`

See also: https://www.baeldung.com/ops/jenkins-parameterized-builds

Only thing I quiet don't get from your question is, what you exactly want to do with the powershell script. A pipeline script in Jenkins is executed on a node, so if the job starts it should be running without any user interaction. To set values from the user input as global variables in a powershell script, you already need to have them available within the jenkins node, hence it's nonsense to set them in the powershell script because they are already available.

Comment: I was asking the best way to do things .. because what i need is a user to login from their local machine  into Office 365 and with those credentials pass them to Jenkins on a remote machine to use throughout my job ; hence do i pass the username and password the user entered from their machine in the querystring , not very secure . Thats why i was asking for the best way to do this

Comment: In that case you should make sure to only allow and use https on the jenkins server. Username and password will be end to end encrypted and that's as secure as every login page on every website out there. What I don't know: If build parameters can be read from logs in jenkins. This would be a security issue indeed. Other solution would be to use Input step https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-input-step/ but I have no idea how this works and where you actually can type the input (in Jenkins UI, in a shell?) and how the input is transferred.

Comment: @Tracey Build parameters are logged by Jenkins, so it's not a good idea to use them for credentials. An `input` step seems to be more secure, as you can define a `password` parameter, which shouldn't be logged (haven't tried it myself): https://stackoverflow.com/a/55351723/7571258

Comment: Well then i could simply add a jenkins user for office 365 and then extract pwd and username to login to azure from powershell az login cmdlets.. The extraction of username and pwd will be secure